# How to make the mobile keyboard appearance bump the div rather than absolutely position itself over it?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm developing a simple chat component and I'm having an issue where, on mobile, if I click the textbox to send a message, rather than bumping up the messages list above it, the virtual keyboard instead absolutely positions itself on top of it.

This is undesirable because I want the user to be able to see the latest message while typing a message. However, I cannot figure out how to rectify this behavior. (and I cannot put the textbox inside the `messages` div because it should always be at the bottom)

I've created an example snippet that demonstrates [the problem here](https://jsfiddle.net/qhdxm71v/3/) (adding bottom margin demonstrates the problem identically to clicking the textbox and having the mobile keyboard pop up)

Basically, if you scroll to the bottom and click the "add margin" button, you'll see that rather than push the contents above it, such that you can still see the latest message, it instead scrolls up. Is there any way to avoid  this?

Here is a copy of the code in case the fiddle goes down:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, there is. The problem here is you are not handling the scroll position of the `.messages` when the `.send-message` div expands (i.e. gets more margin). I presume you want to adjust it so that the scroll position takes the last **visible** message as its pivot (i.e. the last visible message before the div expands has to appear after the div expands, and vice-versa). To adjust said scroll position, here's a minimal working example (I changed your HTML content a little so that you can indicate what the last message is and I adjusted your JS code):

```js
function test() {
  let messageBox = document.querySelector('.messages')
  let beforeMessageBoxHeight = messageBox.clientHeight
  let afterMessageBoxHeight
  let messageBoxHeightDifference
  let beforeScrollTop = messageBox.scrollTop
  let afterScrollTop
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
  afterMessageBoxHeight = messageBox.clientHeight
  messageBoxHeightDifference = beforeMessageBoxHeight - afterMessageBoxHeight
  afterScrollTop = beforeScrollTop + messageBoxHeightDifference
  messageBox.scrollTop = afterScrollTop
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="message">hello1</div>
    <div class="message">hello2</div>
    <div class="message">hello3</div>
    <div class="message">hello4</div>
    <div class="message">hello5</div>
    <div class="message">hello6</div>
    <div class="message">hello7</div>
    <div class="message">hello8</div>
    <div class="message">hello9</div>
    <div class="message">hello1</div>
    <div class="message">hello2</div>
    <div class="message">hello3</div>
    <div class="message">hello4</div>
    <div class="message">hello5</div>
    <div class="message">hello6</div>
    <div class="message">hello7</div>
    <div class="message">hello8</div>
    <div class="message">hello9</div>
    <div class="message">hello1</div>
    <div class="message">hello2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

The idea is:

- Get the `clientHeight` (visible height, read MDN Docs for more details) before the div expands
- Get the `scrollTop` value (how many pixels measured from the topmost visible/invisible element to the topmost visible element)
- When the div (`.send-message`) expands, the visible height (`clientHeight`) automatically reduces in size. The `scrollTop` value is still the same, which means that the topmost visible element **before** the div expands will still be visible. However, that is not what we want: we want the bottommost visible element before the div expands to remain visible
- We measure the height difference after the div expands and before the div expands. Logically, the height difference is what is making the bottom parts of the visible messages (before the div expands) to appear invisible (due to overflow).
- To address that issue, add the height difference to the previous `scrollTop` value so that it scrolls nicely to the bottommost visible message before the div expands.
- Voila, it works. You can apply the same logic when the div retracts.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a pure CSS solution to this, but if this is the best solution then I'll accept it.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Oh, you should mention that in your original question as currently, you implied that any solution is fine in your question *Is there any way to avoid this?*

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been more clear. In any case if there _isn't_ a CSS solution, then I will definitely use this. But just in general pure CSS solutions are generally preferred to JS solutions if they exist, IIRC.