# Prevent div scrolling up when bumped by div below it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587515/how-to-make-the-mobile-keyboard-appearance-bump-the-div-rather-than-absolutely-p#) yesterday but explained it poorly, and didn't specify my desire for a pure-CSS solution, which I think should be possible, so I'm trying again.

Basically, I have an issue where I have a div of scrollable messages and an input field below it. When I click a button, I would like the input field to be bumped up 100 pixels, without having the div of messages scroll as well.

[Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem in its entirety](https://jsfiddle.net/jpzsa8yg/)

As you can see, when you click the "add margin" button, the messages div scrolls up as well. I would like it to stay where it was. Similarly, if you are slightly scrolled up so you can only see the second to last message, clicking the button should similarly retain that position upon click.

The interesting thing is that this behavior is "sometimes" preserved. For example, in some circumstances (which I can't quite deduce) the scroll position is retained. I would just like it to consistently behave as such.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
};

function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin");
}
```

```css
.container {
     width: 400px;
     height: 300px;
     border: 1px solid #333;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
 .messages {
     overflow-y: auto;
     height: 100%;
}
 .send-message {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
 .some-margin {
     margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="messages">
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="send-message">
      <input />
   </div>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello again, I'm the one who answered your question using JS. I'd like to inform you about a thing that you may have misinterpreted. You mentioned: *the messages div scrolls up as well*. Actually, it's not the `div` that is scrolling up, it's the height of the div that is decreasing. So why does this matter? Well, what it means is that the `scrollbar` is not adjusting its position. The scrollbar only *remembers* its position relative from the top of its container. When the div's height decreases, it seems like the scrollbar is scrolling up, but it actually isn't.

Comment: Your post makes perfect sense (in the sense that people know what outcome you want), but I'm just sharing something in case that knowledge isn't apparent to you (in case it may help you to come up with an idea to solve said problem) ;-)

Comment: Yeah very true, thanks for the clarification. It only "looks" like it is scrolling up, because you can't see the lower contents you once could. In reality the scroll position isn't changing. A bit of an illusion. Yeah, that might help come up with a solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is a funny solution that you might like.

What we know about the div that it preserve only the top position of the scrollbar so if the height changed due to any reason the scrollbar will remain the same and this is what causes your issue.

As workaround you can flip the `.messages` 180 degree using `transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);` and flip back the `.message` to cancel flipping the content then the div will maintain the bottom scrollbar (which is top) automatically.

```js
function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);
}

.message
{
  transform: rotate(180deg) scaleX(-1);
}
.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="message">hello1</div>
  <div class="message">hello2</div>
  <div class="message">hello3</div>
  <div class="message">hello4</div>
  <div class="message">hello5</div>
  <div class="message">hello6</div>
  <div class="message">hello7</div>
  <div class="message">hello8</div>
  <div class="message">hello9</div>
  <div class="message">hello10</div>
  <div class="message">hello11</div>
  <div class="message">hello12</div>
  <div class="message">hello13</div>
  <div class="message">hello14</div>
  <div class="message">hello15</div>
  <div class="message">hello16</div>
  <div class="message">hello17</div>
  <div class="message">hello18</div>
  <div class="message">hello19</div>
  <div class="message">hello20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
  <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Comment: This has the issue where scrolling the mousewheel is backwards (scrolling up goes down and scrolling down goes up)

Comment: Ok I spent a lot of time on this but still now other developers have 3 answers that you are not looking for :) i was hoping to help you wish you good luck.
but as an advice upvote who spend time trying to answer your question you will not be charged by doing it.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks anyways

Comment: This is very clever ;-) Unfortunately, the reversed scrolling is a bit off-putting.

Comment: You saved me. I've implemented this solution for bi-directional scrolling https://github.com/LanVukusic/infi-load. demo.

Answer (score 3):

The normal behavior of the scrollbar it to be on the top, so when you set it to the bottom on page load, you have to maintain it your self because when ever the below content pushed it then div scroll will move to the top.

So I have two solutions for you:

1. Reverse the messages inside the messages div so the last message will be the first so the scroll will always be at the top.
2. I created a javascript function to scroll to the bottom of any element so you just call it whenever you want to scroll to the bottom.

```
function scrollbottom(e)
    {
      e.scrollTop = e.clientHeight;
    }
```

Check the snippet

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".messages");

window.onload = function(e){ 
  scrollbottom(elem);
}

function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin");
  scrollbottom(elem);
}

function scrollbottom(e)
{
  e.scrollTop = e.clientHeight;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
  <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to scroll to just scroll to the bottom. I want to maintain its position. Also, it is likely that this can be done without Javascript. From the OP: "Similarly, if you are slightly scrolled up so you can only see the second to last message, clicking the button should similarly retain that position upon click."

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the other way around, by giving the height to the `.messages`  instead of giving it to the `.container` in this case it will not affect the messages `div` but if you are giving it to the `.container` it will push your div because the margin is inside the main div which have a height.

Check this snippet

```js
function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin");
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="message">hello1</div>
  <div class="message">hello2</div>
  <div class="message">hello3</div>
  <div class="message">hello4</div>
  <div class="message">hello5</div>
  <div class="message">hello6</div>
  <div class="message">hello7</div>
  <div class="message">hello8</div>
  <div class="message">hello9</div>
  <div class="message">hello10</div>
  <div class="message">hello11</div>
  <div class="message">hello12</div>
  <div class="message">hello13</div>
  <div class="message">hello14</div>
  <div class="message">hello15</div>
  <div class="message">hello16</div>
  <div class="message">hello17</div>
  <div class="message">hello18</div>
  <div class="message">hello19</div>
  <div class="message">hello20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
  <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the margin needs to be applied to `.send-message`. If you look at my [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587515/how-to-make-the-mobile-keyboard-appearance-bump-the-div-rather-than-absolutely-p#) this is done because it's akin to the margin bump from opening up the virtual keyboard on mobile devices (the margin bottom is just a 1:1 replacement to debug the solution)

Answer (score 2):

The simple workaround is to set the previous `scrollTop` on toggle. Here I am using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to store previous `scrollTop` value, you can use variable either.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
}

function test() {
  let state = document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
  let div = document.querySelector(".messages");

  if (state) {
    div.dataset.top = div.scrollTop;
    div.scrollTop += 100 // same as margin-bottom of .some-margin
  } else {
    div.scrollTop = div.dataset.top;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="message">hello1</div>
    <div class="message">hello2</div>
    <div class="message">hello3</div>
    <div class="message">hello4</div>
    <div class="message">hello5</div>
    <div class="message">hello6</div>
    <div class="message">hello7</div>
    <div class="message">hello8</div>
    <div class="message">hello9</div>
    <div class="message">hello10</div>
    <div class="message">hello11</div>
    <div class="message">hello12</div>
    <div class="message">hello13</div>
    <div class="message">hello14</div>
    <div class="message">hello15</div>
    <div class="message">hello16</div>
    <div class="message">hello17</div>
    <div class="message">hello18</div>
    <div class="message">hello19</div>
    <div class="message">hello20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the js toggle function. I've changed it to a simple hide & show. Also I've added a width on the input tag. You also need to add a position: absolute on the send-message div and bottom: 0 so it stays at the bottom. then place position: relative on the container so that the send message div stays within the container. This means that the message container won't affect the messages themselves and push them up.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
};

function test() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".send-message");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
     width: 400px;
     height: 300px;
     border: 1px solid #333;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     position: relative;
}
 .messages {
     overflow-y: auto;
     height: 100%;
}
 .send-message {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
}
 .send-message input {
     width:100%;
}
 .some-margin {
     margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="messages">
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">test</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
      <div class="message">hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="send-message">
      <input />
   </div>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution. It just seems to hide the send message textbox when you click add margin?

Answer (score 0):

I mean, the following is a CSS only solution that solves exactly your example:

```
.some-margin{margin-bottom:100px;}

.messages{margin-top:-100px;}
```

but I don't think it'll help you with your original problem of the virtual keyboard. But perhaps this can inspire someone else to a solution.

The main problem seems to be that the scrollbar is *already* doing exactly what you want:

***Maintaining its position so the most recently read content is visible.***

Except the scrollbar decides that you wanted to see the TOP of the currently visible content, not the bottom. (It's easier to see if you use numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/1co3x48n/ )

If you're willing to use javascript, there's all sorts of answers:
https://www.google.com/search?q=scrollbar+always+on+bottom+css+site:stackoverflow.com

Honestly, the fact that you can go through ~3+ pages of this and find only Javascript answers tells me that you're not going to find a CSS-only answer, certainly not one that's widely browser-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions provided really seem to work unfortunately. The problem with using `onFocus` for a textbox is that it won't apply if the textbox already has focus. The closest solution I've come up with so far is this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  let chatElem = document.querySelector(".conversations-chat");

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    let diff = this.screenHeight - window.innerHeight;

    chatElem.scrollTop += diff;

    this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;      
  });
}
```

However, this only seems to sometimes work. It works 100% of the time when clicking the textbox, but for some reason when closing the virtual keyboard it only works if it was scrolled up enough. Otherwise it resets to the same position every time (near the bottom, but not quite the bottom).

Not sure what's causing that. Will have to investigate more tomorrow I suppose. This is the closest one thus far though.

Comment: Like we all said in our answers, it seems impossible to do with just CSS alone. (There's a problem with your JS code, which is that **chatElem.scrollTop can't be less than 0**, so if it's too near the top, it tries to become a negative number, becomes 0 instead, then when you make the screen larger again, a scroll appears where there wasn't before.)

Comment: By the same token, chatElem.scrollTop can't be **more than chatElem.scrollHeight - chatElem.offsetHeight** , so it'll create an extra scroll where there was none before if you try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container like in above examples, but then just alter the CSS when you start typing.

I dont set the scrollbar position, just move the whole message container upwards. So whatever your scrollposition might be, will stay the same. At least downwards, of course you will not be able to see the lines at the top.

You should be able to tweak the css to your needs. You could even go without JS if you use :focus or slightly different CSS setup, be creative :)

```js
function activate(){
    document.querySelector("#container").classList.toggle("active");
  }
```

```css
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:100vh;
    max-height:230px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  #messages{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
  }
  #container.active #messages {
    bottom:100px;
  }
  #send-message{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    bottom:0;
    height:28px;
  }
  #container.active #send-message{
    height:100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="messages">
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  <div class="message">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div id="send-message">
    <input id="newmessage" onclick="activate()" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add `document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;` to `test` function when add margin then `scrollTop` go to end 
in load you set `scrolltop` and when you add margin or remove margin `scrolltop` didn't set again 
change you script to like this

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(e){ 
    document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
}

function test() {
    document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
            document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one more approach that we can explore. If we don't want to play with scroll position and if it is ok if we shrink messages container without loosing usability. Then we can try something like below. For better understanding view the output in full page.

```js
window.onload = function(e) {
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
};

function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin");
  document.querySelector(".messages").classList.toggle("scale");
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}

.messages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* leave 1.4 rem space for input */
  height: calc(300px - 1.4rem);
  width: 100%;
}

.scale {
  /*half of the 100 margin */
  top: -50px;
  /* scale  = (totalHeight - 100px)/totalHeight */
  transform: scaleY(0.64);
}

.send-message {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello</div>
    <div class="message">hello4</div>
    <div class="message">hello3</div>
    <div class="message">hello2</div>
    <div class="message">hello1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
    <input style="width:100%" />
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">add margin</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

A pure imperfect CSS approach that I can come up with is the following:

```js
window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', test)

function test() {
  document.querySelector(".send-message").classList.toggle("some-margin")
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').classList.toggle('wrapper--transformed')
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.messages {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper--transformed {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some-margin {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class = "wrapper">
      <div class="message">hello1</div>
      <div class="message">hello2</div>
      <div class="message">hello3</div>
      <div class="message">hello4</div>
      <div class="message">hello5</div>
      <div class="message">hello6</div>
      <div class="message">hello7</div>
      <div class="message">hello8</div>
      <div class="message">hello9</div>
      <div class="message">hello1</div>
      <div class="message">hello2</div>
      <div class="message">hello3</div>
      <div class="message">hello4</div>
      <div class="message">hello5</div>
      <div class="message">hello6</div>
      <div class="message">hello7</div>
      <div class="message">hello8</div>
      <div class="message">hello9</div>
      <div class="message">hello1</div>
      <div class="message">hello2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
<button>add margin</button>
```

The topmost section has a little problem when margin is there. The trick here is using negative margin and using translate to "scroll up" (not really a scroll, just an illusion) the `wrapper` div.

Comment: The topmost section issue is a bit of an issue, yeah. Also, does this presume knowing the exact size of the mobile keyboard to know how much to compensate by? I'm not sure if I have access to that information.

Comment: To answer your question: yes. The above technique must know the exact height of the keyboard. However, there are ways using JS to determine the height of an element and change the CSS.

Comment: How would you determine the height of the mobile virtual keyboard?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Is that virtual keyboard an element of HTML (e.g. `div`)?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Oh. Then is it correct to assume that the virtual keyboard to which you are referring is the native keyboard that the mobile device has? What about in the desktop? How is that virtual keyboard generated?

Comment: Yes, the virtual keyboard refers to the native one in mobile devices. This isn't an issue on desktop, only mobile.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Then you can use `resize` as answered in your other question in regard to mobile devices. I'm not sure how you can use CSS only for that (that is, getting the height of a keyboard that CSS has no way of accessing beforehand). Someone might come up with a solution, though.

Comment: Giving the bounty to this one since his comment reinforced the idea I should use the resize event which led to to [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698633/962155)

Answer (score -2):

It can very simply be addressed with anchor names. Look at the JS fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/gvbz93sx/

**HTML Change**
    `<a name="bottom"></a>`

**JS Change**
    `document.location.hash = "#bottom";`