# Force mobile onscreen keyboard to not be position absolute?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, mobile

I'm developing a chat and it works on desktop but on mobile when you select the textbox and it automatically opens the virtual onscreen keyboard, the onscreen keyboard seems to overlay itself (similar to `position:fixed` over the messages div, rather than bumping it.

Basically, the messages div should retain its scroll position rather than adjusting. If you can see the latest message, you still see the latest message. If you can only see the second latest message, similarly, after opening the keyboard you should be able to see it.

[image: Here's a picture:]

Here's a full [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx28kmnv/) demo demonstrating the issue.

```js
 window.onload = function(e){ 
  document.querySelector(".messages").scrollTop = 10000;
 }

 function test() {
  document.querySelector(".mobile-keyboard").classList.toggle("show")
 }
```

```css
 .container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 .messages {
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .send-message {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
  
  .mobile-keyboard {
 display: none;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #ccc;
  }
  
  .show {
 display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="message">hello1</div>
  <div class="message">hello2</div>
  <div class="message">hello3</div>
  <div class="message">hello4</div>
  <div class="message">hello5</div>
  <div class="message">hello6</div>
  <div class="message">hello7</div>
  <div class="message">hello8</div>
  <div class="message">hello9</div>
  <div class="message">hello10</div>
  <div class="message">hello11</div>
  <div class="message">hello12</div>
  <div class="message">hello13</div>
  <div class="message">hello14</div>
  <div class="message">hello15</div>
  <div class="message">hello16</div>
  <div class="message">hello17</div>
  <div class="message">hello18</div>
  <div class="message">hello19</div>
  <div class="message">hello20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="send-message">
 <div class="mobile-keyboard"></div>
 <input />
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="test()">show keyboard</button>
```

I believe this should be able to be accomplished with editing the HTML and CSS only, but I have not been able to figure it out. I'd prefer a CSS approach, but a robust JavaScript one should work too.

The solution shouldn't edit the CSS for the `mobile-keyboard` because it is not possible to edit as far as I know. The div I have created there is a substitute for the real keyboard that automatically appears on mobile when you select the textbox (which has the same effect on appearance as the regular mobile keyboard in that it doesn't bump the contents)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can control where the mobile device pops up the keyboard

Comment: Well, how does every app do it then? None of the messaging sites / apps I use have this problem on mobile, so they must be getting around it somehow.

Comment: Is this a mobile app you've created or are you referring to a regular web page in a browser in the mobile device?

Comment: It's a regular webpage viewed on a mobile device in the Chrome browser.

Comment: well, a browser doesn't have control over the keyboard overlay as far as I'm aware -

Comment: Well, hopefully someone has an idea for a workaround then. This issue is extremely annoying to my users.

Comment: every site I've ever made, I've never even thought about the keyboard, it just works as it should, because the mobile device knows what to do

Comment: so, the only difference between what you get and what you want is the scroll position?

Comment: In this case the keyboard is acting contrary to every other messaging platform in that it changes your scroll position when you open it. My users hate this and complain about how it's different from other sites and apps and how they don't like having to constantly scroll back to where they were every time they go to send a message.

Comment: it has not changed the scroll position ... look at the first line ... it is `hello7` in both left and right in what you describe as "bad" ... what you want is for the scroll position to change ... why would displaying an overlay change the scroll position of what's underneath ... unless you tell it to do so :p

Comment: Perhaps this is semantics. What I'm trying to get across is the desire for the bottom of the messages div to maintain its presence before and after opening the keyboard

Comment: yeah, I get what you want. If you always want to scroll to the bottom, then scroll to the bottom using javascript when the keyboard button is pressed

Comment: I do not wish this though. Like mentioned in the OP, I want the presence to be maintained. That is, if the bottom message is `hello19`, then upon opening the keyboard the bottom message should still be `hello19`. Scrolling to the bottom would make it `hello20`.

Comment: then you'll need to do some fancy calculations - or maybe not - let me google

Comment: I have working code for android devices - not sure about iOS though, as I have no such devices

Comment: Hello again, I answered your question in regard to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59587994/9060223 Did my solution not work for mobile devices? I tried pasting your code above and my JS code with a little tweak and ran it on JSFiddle full-screen mode (on my Android phone), it seems to do what you wanted.

Comment: @Richard Hi again Richard. I realized after I posted that that question that although your answer worked for that circumstance, it wouldn't work with my specific case, so I instead posted this question. The issue with yours is that in reality there isn't an `add margin` button. Rather, the onscreen keyboard appears when the user selects the textbox, so you can't really grab the scroll values beforehand (it's too late at that point)

Comment: I see. Then I assume that the `show keyboard` button is not, in reality, there either (which you included in this case). So your case is: I focus on the textbox and the div automatically gets margin. Is that the case? I suppose that the margin is given through some sort of event listener (probably `click` in this case). Is it really not possible to grab the scroll values before you add the margin to the div that represents the keyboard?

Comment: Yeah I included that button to attempt to replicate what bringing up the keyboard does since it's very hard to debug these things on mobile, but I don't think I did a very good job providing a 1:1 correspondence unfortunately. I'm not exactly sure how the mobile virtual keyboard is defined (whether or not it's an HTML element or if you can even inspect it). Similarly, I'm not sure how to grab the scroll value from before the keyboard is brought up

Answer (score -1):

calling the function below, passing in the scrolling element as the argument, works in Android mobile devices

```
function bottomScroller(scroller) {
    let scrollBottom = scroller.scrollHeight - scroller.scrollTop - scroller.clientHeight;
    scroller.addEventListener('scroll', () => scrollBottom = scroller.scrollHeight - scroller.scrollTop - scroller.clientHeight;
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => scroller.scrollTop = scroller.scrollHeight - scrollBottom - scroller.clientHeight;
};
```

As for iOS - not sure, as I don't use Apple

Comment: Hey cool thanks this seems to work alright, but I think has a slight issue because closing the keyboard causes the div to scroll to the bottom. That is, opening the keyboard seems to work, but closing it doesn't retain the position.

Comment: works 100% for me ... firefox on mobile

Comment: I've debugged this some more and it has the same issue as my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680546/962155 That is, it works perfectly unless you are scrolled within `MOBILE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT` pixels of the bottom of the div, in which case closing the keyboard causes it to scroll to the bottom.